# Generating discrete time periodic signal in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, signal-processing, periodicity

x[t] is a discrete time periodic signal defined as follows over one period

```
x[t] = {1 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4.....}
```

I want to generate this as a periodic signal in the interval [0,100] in Matlab. But, I am unable to write a code for this.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean by "periodic signal" as the signal you showed there its not periodic, unless you only have shown 1 period.

Comment: @AnderBiguri yes it is for 1 period. I have already mentioned this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try `arrayfun` like below

```
X = arrayfun(@(k) 1:k, 2:4, "UniformOutput",false);
x = repmat([X{:}],1,2);
```

which gives

```
x =

   1   2   1   2   3   1   2   3   4   1   2   1   2   3   1   2   3   4
```

Comment: I don't want only this signal, I want this signal to repeat itself. The signal "x" you are getting is over one period. I want to  get something like this- x={1 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4, 1 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4, ......}

Comment: @SeñoraPenn See my update, which have two repetitions for example, and you can have more according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In matlab if you want to generate a periodic signal there many methods one of them is :

```
%x is array that represent discrete time signal.
%y is generated periodic signal 
%n the number of periods

temp=x'*ones(1,n);
y=temp(:);
% where x' is transpose of x.
% if we suppose x=[1,2,3]
% if we want to repeat it five times we can say n = 5
% then temp will equal [ 1 1 1 1 1
%                        2 2 2 2 2
%                        3 3 3 3 3]
%fianlly y will equal [1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3]
```

Comment: @AIASAD WAIL The discrete time signal which I have mentioned is different from this one.

Comment: The `repmat` function does this in an easier-to-read manner.

Comment: @CrisLuengo can you please write the code or give hints?

Comment: @SeñoraPenn send your math equations that you want to represent it .

Comment: @SeñoraPenn send your math equations that you want to represent it .

Comment: @AlASADWAIL this is the equation "over one period" x[t] = {1 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4.....}. That is the signal repeats itself after this like x[t] = {1 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4, 1 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4, ........}

Comment: so there is not a problem with my answer you can make like this :
~ x=[ 1 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4]; %or any generated signal
 temp=x'*ones(1,9);
y=temp(:)~